# Select triggers mouseout/mouseleave event

Tags: jquery, html, mouseleave, mouseout

I hide the following div -

```
<div id="testDIV" style="background-color: #4cff00; padding: 20px;">
        <select>
            <option>OptionA</option>
            <option>OptionB</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

with this code -

```
$("#testDIV").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, function () { $(this).remove(); });
        });
```

If user select an option the mouseleave also triggers...

How can I disable the mouseout/mouseleave events when user select an option.

Comment: What code have you tried to stop the div disappearing once the user has selected an option? Please elaborate on your question. Would you like the box to remain if the user has selected an option or did you still want it to trigger the mouseout?

Comment: You can add default first option like "- not selected -" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've put your code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkny8t76/) to test, and on MacOs X, I don't have the issue your having.

I'm specifying the OS, because styling is different on Windows and Mac Os X.

Could it be that your options are going out of your div when the `select` is open ?

This would explain the behaviour. The mouse would be out of the div when it's selected.

If it's the case, the solution would be to set a `height` big enough so that the options wouldn't go out of the div.

Hope it helps you.

EDIT:

You can test the target of the event with "this" which is the element attach to the event. If the are different, then you don't trigger the hide function.

```
$("#testDIV").mouseleave(function (event) {
    if (event.target !== this) return;

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, function () {
    $(this).remove(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: The question that was asked was "How can I disable the mouseout/mouseleave events when user select an option."

Comment: True, but without identifying to source of the problem, we can't solve it.

Comment: When the select list is open all options are within the parent div area. I am using IE for the above question.

Comment: @Elhebert Also in your example, I am running Mac OSX as well, as soon as I click on the select box the js is triggered.

Comment: I tested it on safari, google chrome and Opera. I don't have that behaviour on Chrome or Safari, but I do on Opera. Anyway, try this solution : https://jsfiddle.net/zkny8t76/1/

Comment: @Elhebert, tested it in IE and FF and both trigger mouseout event when hovering over a select option

Comment: @S.L. I'm now on mobile, but IIRC you could stop the propagation with the proper methods on the event. Or you could add `if (event.target !== this) return;` inside the event listener, but before you trigger the hide function. I'll edit my answer when I'm back on my mac.

Comment: Thanks to Elhebert the **if (event.target !== this) return;** Solved the issue.

Comment: I'm glad it solved your issue. Events are quite challenging. I edited my answer with that solution for futur references.

Comment: If I click the select and the options shows and I move out the mouse to the parent div and re move the mouse to the options list than mouseleave triggers...., any idea how to prevent it ?

Comment: Being on mobile, I can't test it,  it I'd with either stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation, but I'm not sure. If you haven't found a solution when I get back on my laptop, I'll run some test and let you know.

Comment: The code I use in the select mouseenter, mousemove, mouseleave follows - **event.stopPropagation();
                            if (event.target == this) return;**

Comment: @S.L. I updated my answer ;) Simply use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: @S.L. So, any news ? Did it fixed your issue ? If it did, don't forget to validate the answer (for futur reference)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```js
var $div = $("#testDIV");

function mLeave(e){
  $div.animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, function () { $div.remove(); });
}
$div.on('mouseleave', mLeave );

$("#testDIV select").click(function () {
  $div.off('mouseleave', mLeave );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testDIV" style="background-color: #6287c1; padding: 20px;">
        <select>
            <option>OptionA</option>
            <option>OptionB</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it should only remove the html when the user has selected the option A or B?
Maybe add an default "Please select" and check the value first. If nothing has been chosen than don't remove the html.

HTML

```
<div id="testDIV" style="background-color: #4cff00; padding: 20px;">
<select>
  <option value="default">Please select</option>
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
</select>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
   var optionVal;

    $("#testDIV").mouseleave(function () {
      if(optionVal != "default"){
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, function () { $(this).remove(); });
      }
    });
    $("#testDIV select").on('click change', function () {
      optionVal = $(this).val();
    });
```